# How to restrict data pump logon to localhost

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, datapump

I have a user in Oracle 12c database that will be used to run full data pump export and import. I would like to restrict logons from that user to localhost.

I have tried to create logon trigger:

```
create or replace trigger logon_trigger 
  after logon on database
declare
  host varchar2(50);
begin 
  host := trim(lower(sys_context('USERENV', 'HOST')));
  if lower(user) = '<data pump user>' then
    if host <> '<hostname>' then
      raise_application_error(-20000, 'Login not allowed');
    end if;
  end if;
end;
/
```

I can see from the audit trail that this trigger has fired (ORA-20000: Login not allowed) but the user is still allowed to logon from remote host.

This restriction works for normal users but not for the data pump user. I suspect this has something to do with the roles exp_full_database and imp_full_database.

Is there some way to make this trigger work or should I use local OS authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER Privilege Causes Logon Trigger to Skip Errors (Doc ID 265012.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=265012.1)

```
ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER Privilege Behavior with Database Logon Trigger
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Logon triggers can be used to mediate database access: when the restrictive 
conditions are not met, an application error with a message is raised that 
causes the logon to be denied.

...

However, we need to keep at least one user who can still connect when there is 
a problem : a fallback mechanism must exist where an administrative user is 
exempt from such errors of a prohibited connection. 

Any user granted the ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER system privilege can still 
connect : instead of getting the error causing the session to be terminated, 
the error is recorded in the alert.log and a trace file in user_dump_dest.
```

And:

```
select * from dba_sys_privs where privilege = 'ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER';

GRANTEE                        PRIVILEGE                                ADM
------------------------------ ---------------------------------------- ---
WMSYS                          ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER              NO 
DBA                            ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER              YES
SYS                            ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER              NO 
IMP_FULL_DATABASE              ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER              NO
```

So yes, you can try local OS authentication.

Comment: you should know that quoting from an MOS Doc is a violation of the terms of use of MOS.  Just cite the source with a comment of why it is being cited.

Comment: Thank you for the link, this explains the situation. Maybe I will create two different usernames, one for export and one for import. Export needs to be run automatically but import is only run on demand.